# jQuery: Change an attribute value through variable

Tags: jquery

How would you change a attribute value when you're trying to initially set the attribute to a variable:

```
<div class="random" aria-expanded="false">
  ...
</div>

// setting the attribute value to variable `getAttrValue`
var getAttrValue = $('.random').attr("aria-expanded");


if ( getAttrValue == "false" ) {
  // try to set the aria-expanded to true
} else {
  // try to set the aria-expanded to false
}
```

I can do it like this:

```
if ( getAttrValue == false ) {
  $('.random').attr("aria-expanded", "true");
} else {
  $('.random').attr("aria-expanded", "false");
}
```

But I was trying to see if I can utilize the variable and shorten the coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `$('.random')` as a variable to avoid repeated DOM queries. Each time you do `$('.random')`, jQuery searches the DOM for items that fit your selector. Instead, you can do it *once* and store it in a variable. Not only does it shorten your code, but it makes it run faster.

Because your attributes are going to be string values, you'll need to do a  string comparison.

```
var $r = $(".random");
var getAttrValue = $r.attr("aria-expanded");
$r.attr("aria-expanded", getAttrValue=="false");
```

By using `==` ([Equality Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)), the expression `getAttrValue=="false"` will evaluate to `true` or `false`.

Comment: I had to change the boolean to actual strings, if I did the `!` logical NOT operator, is it supposed to know to switch between `"true"` and `"false"`? even though these boolean are actual strings?

Comment: If it just does getAttrValue=="false", how does it go back to "true"? is this supposed to toggle?

Comment: It will set it to the opposite of what it currently is. Think about it... `x == "false"` will return `true` if `x` is `"false"`, and `false` if `x` is `"true"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.random').attr("aria-expanded", getAttrValue == false);
```